# ViewBag detecting last item MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have list of objects in ViewBag. Is there any way to check if that item is the last in that ViewBag in Razor view?

```
@if (ViewBag.List != null)
{
    foreach(var item in ViewBag.List)
    {
        if(item[0] == **LAST ITEM** ) // here I want to check if it is the last item in my ViewBag.List
        { 
            /* do stuff */ 
        } 
    }
}
```

EDIT: I store there years as an anonymous objects

```
public object GetYears(){
    return result.Distinct().OrderBy(i => i.startYear).Select(c => new[]
                {
                    c.startYear
                });
}

ViewBag.List = GetYears();
```

Comment: What are you stroing in ViewBag.List show that code.

Comment: That `ViewBag.List` what type is it? `List`, `Array`....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `ViewBag.List` implements `IEnumerable<T>` you could use `Last()`
You would need to `cast` the list in your `ViewBag` in order to access methods of `IEnumerable` or accessing by index, I would assume that `startYear` is an `int`.

```
@if (ViewBag.List != null)
{
    var last_item = (ViewBag.List as IEnumerable<int[]>).Last();
    foreach(var item in ViewBag.List)
    {
        if(item[0] == last_item[0]) // here I want to check if it is the last item in my ViewBag.List
        { 
            /* do stuff */ 
        } 
    }
}
```

Or you can use the traditional way using `Count` and accesing the element by `index`

```
@if (ViewBag.List != null)
{
    IEnumerable<int[]> viewbag_list = (ViewBag.List as IEnumerable<int[]>);
    var last_item = viewbag_list[viewbag_list.Count()-1];
    foreach(var item in ViewBag.List)
    {
        if(item[0] == last_item[0]) // here I want to check if it is the last item in my ViewBag.List
        { 
            /* do stuff */ 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: ViewBag doesn't have functions like Count() or Last(), I've already tried that :)

Comment: of course ViewBag doesn't have that methods, but the List stored in the viewbag is a IEnumerable, and hasit. Probably you would need to do a cast. I make an edit.

Comment: I update the answer with differents ways to do it, and with the casting of the viewbag list. It should work, let me know if don't.

Comment: Thanks, now this is working with casting, the only problem was, that item was not equal to last_item, so I you can update that to item[0] == last_item[0]. Really helpful answer ! :)

Comment: My bad. I forgot to add the `[0]`. I edit my answer accordingly. Glad to help!

Comment: Cheers! :) by the way, is there any way to use lambda expression for that kind of list which has been casted? I would like to make something like 
var lastFiltered = (ViewBag.List as IEnumerable<int []>).Where(m => m.Value < 2015).Last();

Comment: I think that the way you put it in your comment would work without problems. Isn't it?

Comment: maybe the type int[] doesn't have property Value, because m => m. gives only GetValue and SetValue when I try to do something to that side

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I think that what you put in your comment was only an example. Try this: `var lastFiltered = (ViewBag.List as IEnumerable<int []>).Where(m => m[0] < 2015).Last();`